# Java 11 cannot resolve method, if is it a bug?

Tags: java, java-11

I have a strange compilation error with Java 11 (OpenJDK):

> cannot find symbol:   method
>   not(java.util.function.Predicat<java.lang.Class>)   location:
>   interface java.util.function.Predicate

Intellij Idea does not show any warnings nor errors... What could be wrong?
Cast to Predicate<Class> and invalidate Idea's cache did not help.

```
    public class ConditionForBean implements Condition {
        @FunctionalInterface
        private interface NoException<T, R> {
            R apply(T t) throws Exception;
        }
        private static Function<String, Class> runtimeOf(NoException<String, Class> f) {
            return (str) -> {
                try {
                    return f.apply(str);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
            String[] beanNames = conditionContext.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinitionNames();
            return Arrays.stream(beanNames)
                    .map(conditionContext.getBeanFactory()::getBeanDefinition)
                    .map(BeanDefinition::getBeanClassName)
                    .map(runtimeOf(Class::forName))
                    .filter(Predicate.not(ConditionalBean.class::equals)) // error
                    .map(Class::getInterfaces)
                    .noneMatch(interfaces -> Arrays.asList(interfaces).contains(Excludable.class));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using JDK 11 to compile this code?

Comment: `java.util.function.Predicat<java.lang.Class>` I hope this is some sort of copy/paste error because if it isn't, you typoed Predicate as Predicat somewhere not shown in this code, likely in `ConditionalBean`.

Comment: Your problem is you're compiling against the wrong JDK version, and its not finding the `not()` method added in Java 11.  That said, I think you've gone a little mref-happy...the filter argument would be better written in the obvious way, and similar for the first map.

Comment: It is definitely java 11: Information:javac 11 was used to compile java sources.
For Predicat - just mistyped when editing the post,
is was:
Error:(40, 56) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method not(java.util.function.Predicate<java.lang.Class>)
  location: interface java.util.function.Predicate. Maven builds this project gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was so stupid...
I have

<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
    <source>1.9</source>
    <target>1.9</target>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>

In pom.xml, after replacing 1.9 to 1.11 it has gone.